# implementing stack class using link list to validate xml file

Tags: c++, validation

Implement your Stack class using link list. Use your stack class to validate XML file.
Write C++ program to read XML file from command line and validate XML matching case insensitive beginning and ending tags.
Give error messages to all missing corresponding begin or end tags and continue validating all XML file.

Example to correct XML document.

```
<Students>
    <Student>
        <Name>Tanver</Name>
        <RollNo>312</RollNo>
    <student>
<students>
```

Example to incorrect XML document, “head” and “html” end tag missing. “name” begin tag missing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first page</title>
        </name>
<body>
    My first page
</body>
```

Comment: This looks a lot like homework.  If we just give you an answer then you won't learn much.  Better if you have an attempt, even if you only try to solve a small part of the problem.  We can then give you hints and help you.  End result: you learn something.

Comment: @user3397832 Actually, unless it is an omission, the first XML is incorrect too. End tags for student and students are missing the slash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also training C++ and thought this was a nice exercise. Here is what I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Item {
    public:
        T data;
        Item *prev;
        Item(T& data, Item *prev) : data(data), prev(prev) {}
};

template <typename T>
class StackIterator {
    public:
        Item<T> *curr;

        StackIterator(Item<T> *curr) : curr(curr) {}

        T& operator*() { 
            return curr->data;
        }

        StackIterator<T>& operator++() {
            curr = curr->prev; 
            return *this; 
        }

        friend bool operator!=(const StackIterator<T>& l, const StackIterator<T>& r) {
            return l.curr != r.curr;
        }
};

template <typename T>
class Stack {
    typedef StackIterator<T> iterator;

    public:
        Item<T> *last=NULL;

        T& back(void) {
            return last->data;
        }

        void push_back(T d) {
            last = new Item<T>(d, last);
        }

        void pop_back(void) {
            Item<T> *curr = last;
            last = last->prev;
            delete curr;
        }

        ~Stack() {
            while (last) pop_back();
        }

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(last);
        }

        iterator end() {
            return iterator(NULL);
        }
};

int main() {
    string xml[] = {"<Students>", "<Student>", "<Name>", "Tanver", "</Name>",
        "<RollNo>", "312", "</RollNo>", "</Student>", "</Students>"};

    //string xml[] = {"<html>", "<head>", "<title>", "My first page", "</title>",
    //    "</name>", "<body>", "My first page", "</body>"};

    regex opentag("^<(.*)>$");
    regex closetag("^</(.*)>$");
    smatch m;

    Stack<string> v;
    //vector<string> v;

    for (auto& it : xml) {
        if (regex_search(it, m, closetag)) {
            for (auto& x : m)
                if (x == v.back()) {
                    v.pop_back();
                    cout << "closing " << x << "\n";
                } else {
                    cout << "Tag " << x << " was not opened\n";
                }
        } else if (regex_search(it, m, opentag)) {
            for (auto &x : m) {
                cout << "opening " << x << "\n";
                v.push_back(x);
            }
        } else {
            cout << "data: " << it << "\n";
        }
    }

    for (auto& x : v) {
        cout << "Tag " << x << " was not closed\n";
    }
}
```

I didn't bother about the reading from the command line part. Of course, one can also skip the whole `StackIterator` thing, but that would be like writing the whole thing in plain C which I normally do.

Hope this helps!